# How to modify an excel before downloading it with Phpspreadsheet?

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to save an excel using php://output but I want to modify it before downloading it. I tried this but obviously is not working.

```
            $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
            $response = new StreamedResponse(
            static function () use ($writer) {
                $file = $writer->save('php://output');

                //$zip = new \ZipArchive();
                //if ($zip->open('php://output') === TRUE) {
                //   <do something>
                //}
            },
        );

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; 
    filename=<file.xlsx>');
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0');

    return $response;
```

Comment: Can you post additional code (what`s going on before) - I imagine you have some kind of `Spreadsheet` variable before and `$writer` is created from that?

Comment: @Evil_skunk Yes, I create an spreadsheet and I fill it with data, that's fine. The problem is just the commented part.

Comment: but you want to change the excel file (content) before downloading? - so maybe change it before writing to php output

Comment: The thing is I don't need to change the content (like the cells), I need to change the .xml files that are inside the .xlsx. So I have to save it first to generate those files. That's the reason of the ziparchive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would seperate this into 3 steps

1) write the spreadsheet to a file

```
$filename = "filename.xlsx";
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save($file);
```

2) load the file (as a zip-archive) change it and save the changed file

```
$zip= new \ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($filename) === TRUE) {
    //load a file from the xlsx (zip)
    $xmlContentOld = $zip->getFromName("whatever.xml");
    $xmlContentNew = $xmlContentOld . "<addedTag></addedTag>";
    //Delete the old file and write the file with new content into the archive
    $zip->deleteName("whatever.xml")
    $zip->addFromString("whatever.xml", $xmlContentNew );
    //close and update zip
    $zip->close();
}
```

3) serve the changed archive file to the browser

```
$fp = fopen($filename, 'rb');

// send the right headers
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));

fpassthru($fp);
```